# CORS error when attempting to load gltf model from google drive

Tags: html, three.js, google-drive-api, cors, aframe

I'm currently attempting to load a gltf model into my Aframe scene from Google Drive like this:

`<a-entity gltf-model="url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={redacted})"></a-entity>`

But I'm getting the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={redacted}' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I'm using a python SimpleHTTPServer configured to allow CORS from here: https://gist.github.com/mkows/cd2122f427ea722bf41aa169ef762001

When I upload an image to google drive and attempt to load that using 
`<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={redacted}" />` the image loads fine.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using a python SimpleHTTPServer configured to allow CORS

Not for this.

That request is being serviced by the server responsible for `drive.google.com`, not `localhost:8000`.

You've applied the CORS headers to the wrong server.

---

Since you don't control Google Drive's response headers, consider hosting the file elsewhere (or proxying it through you own server, which is effectively the same thing).

Comment: Okay, for this project I don't have the freedom of hosting a web server so do you know if Dropbox or Onedrive would have the same issue? I'm just looking for a simple place to store and serve a few files for free. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, any idea why an image loads fine but the model doesn't?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068 — see the section "Why you can display data in the page without reading it with JS
"

Comment: Thanks, update: just tried out mediafire and it works